TV show about Robin Hood with a naked witch arriving in the village
So, this is a long shot, but I'm trying anyways.
I once saw something on TV and I can't remember what it's called, and it's really bugging me.
I'll start by saying it looked pretty old, the quality wasn't that great (as in seeing black dots appearing every now and then). I'm also not certain about if it was a TV show or a movie. I think it was a TV show, but give it the benefit of the doubt.
The story was kind of weird (and I only remember a certain part of what I saw), so bear with me. If I recall correctly, it was a Robin Hood story in which a completely naked (ginger?) witch arrived in a village. Over time, people of the village would fall in love with her (even Friar Tuck). Robin would try to stop her but would get captured.
That's all I can remember, unfortunately.
Details imported from comment
First of all, it was in English, but I have no idea where it could have been made. I remember a lot of shots that happened in the forest (and I believe most of the accents were British, although I don't remember that quite as clearly).
I also have no idea when it was really made, but I saw it when we still had a bad TV (making the quality uncertain) and I was still rather young, somewhere between 2000 and 2005, to give you a time-span to look into.
I don't remember much about the other actors unfortunately, perhaps about Robin who had a goatee and brown hair.

Hey! Welcome to Movies & TV! Hope we can help. Is there any chance that you remember...
a) What language it was in and/or where you think the show or movie was made?
b) How old you think is old (60s, 70s...)?
c) When or where you watched it?
Or anything else (e.g. what the actors besides the witch looked like) that might help us pinpoint the show or movie? Thanks!

First of all, it was in English but I have no idea where it could have been made. I remember a lot of shots that happened in the forest (and I believe most of the accents were british, although I don't remember that quite as clearly). I also have no idea when it was really made, but I saw it when we still had a bad tv (making the quality uncertain) and I was still rather young, somewhere between 2000 and 2005, to give you a timespan to look into. I don't remember much about the other actors unfortunately, perhaps about Robin who had a goatee and brown hair. Thanks again for helping out!

It's the episode Godiva of The New Adventures of Robin Hood:

When Marion announces that she is engaged to be married, everyone is
  thrilled, except for Robin. Little John and Friar Tuck go to a nearby
  village to organise an engagement party, but become trapped by Godiva,
  a sorceress and former apprentice of Olwyn. She is seeking revenge on
  Robin, whom she loves, but who imprisoned her in a tree years
  previously. Godiva captures Robin, and tries to seize power in the
  land. It is up to the women to rescue Robin and defeat Godiva, since
  they are immune to her attractions

You can see Robin with goatee and brown hair, as well as the naked witch, in the first minute of this clip.

Oh My GOD thank you so much!
